# Runtime complexity of 4 Nested For Loops

Tags: loops, for-loop, runtime, complexity-theory

Can you please tell me what is the Runtime complexity of 4 Nested For Loops?

I have 4 nested for loops

For { For { For { For {

Answer (score 0):

Well depends on what you're looping against. If you're looping 4 times against an array of N elements, then its time complexity is N to the power of 4, therefore O(N⁴).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it would be O(n^4), but it depends on the algorithm being used.